# NSDictionary allKeys and allValues order changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a view controller that has a table view on it, and, for that table view's data source, I use an `NSDictionary`that contains two keys and two values. I initialize the dictionary with an object literal, and I also have an `NSArray` that contains values that should correspond to the values in the dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Key1" : @"Value1", @"Key2" : @"Value2"};
NSArray *arr = @[@"Value for Key 1", @"Value for Key 2"];
```

In my table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I have the following

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (!cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

cell.textLabel.text = dict.allKeys[indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = dict.allValues[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

return cell;
```

However, regardless of the order in which I initialize `dict` (it could be `@{@"Key2" : @"Value2", @"Key1" : @"Value1"}`), value 2 will always come first. This causes issues for when I add more objects to the dictionary, as the indexes in `arr` must match up with the indexes in `dict`, and this issue also makes the table view appear in a way different from what I want it to. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

To help visualize the problem, here is a diagram to demonstrate

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Key1" : @"Value1", @"Key2" : @"Value2"};
----------------------------------------
Table view
----------------------------------------
  [Value 2] [Key 2]
----------------------------------------
  [Value 1] [Key 1]
----------------------------------------
//if I change the order in the dictionary, the order in the table view remains the same
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Key2" : @"Value2", @"Key1" : @"Value1"};
----------------------------------------
Table view
----------------------------------------
  [Value 2] [Key 2]
----------------------------------------
  [Value 1] [Key 1]
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Dictionaries do not retain their order. If order is important to you, you need to use an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is going wrong here. NSDictionary is an unordered collection. To say "the order I added them" has no meaning.

If you want to access the keys in a certain order then you'll either have to store an array along side your dictionary or get the keys and then sort them and use that to access the values in that order.